# Can We represent -128 in 8-bit notation?

Tags: binary, numbers

I am wondering how can We represent -128 in 8-bit notation?reason for getting this doubt is -128 representation in binary form is 1000 0000.In this MSB is 1 which is the sign bit and magnitude is 0 which is not -128.what is the solution for this?

Comment: `-128 = 0b10000000, -1 = 0b11111111, 127 = 0b01111111`.

Comment: How about sign bit?

Comment: As you can see in `-128` and `-1`, the first bit (sign) is set to 1.

Comment: What is the relation between -128 and -1?

Comment: They are both negative. I wrote the binary representation of `-1` just in order to give you an additional reference point.

Comment: sign-magnitude is one type of representation and twos-complement is another type. You might be confusing the two.

Answer (score 1):

> In this MSB is 1 which is the sign bit and magnitude is 0 which is not -128.

That's just how [two's complement signed binary integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) work. Basically, the bits define a value, and when the sign bit is set, we subtract 256 (for an 8-bit value) from the value (logically, not literally). The unsigned pattern `1000 0000` defines the value 128. If you're treating it as unsigned, you see that the sign bit is set so you subtract 256 from that and get -128. The unsigned pattern `1000 0001` defines the number 129. As a signed number, again because the sign bit is set you subtract 256 from it and get -127. And so on.